# Is there a generic name for something with advent calendar-like windows?

Tags: single-word-requests

Advent calendars are a panel with little windows that reveal some surprise inside (maybe a picture, sweet, or some message). It seems unlikely to me that advent calendars are the only device that has this form factor (windows with things inside). As such, is there a generic name for such a device, independent of its function in the religious holiday?

Comment: While one might take Wikipedia with a pinch of salt, its [article on the Advent Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_calendar) doesn't mention anything else except *Julkalender,* a "word for a Yule—or Christmas—calendar". The only mention of "countdown calendar" is in a photo depicting a large number 11 which is torn off to reveal 10, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The ones for other events are called "countdown calendars":

- [Midnight Ramadan Mosque Countdown Calendar](https://www.etsy.com/ca/listing/526543299/midnight-ramadan-mosque-countdown)
- [Hanukkah Countdown Calendar](https://www.etsy.com/listing/118053033/hanukkah-countdown-calendar-whimsical?gpla=1&gao=1&)

There are other things that can be described as having "windows with things inside" but I don't think there's a term that generalizes well. For example, a [pill organizer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082B4LCGJ) is described with just those words.

For an adjective, maybe *compartmentalized*.